# How to get a directory path in pyqt6 via QFileDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt

Name: PyQt6 
Version: 6.1.0

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

HOME_PATH = os.getenv("HOME")
...

dir_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
    parent=self,
    caption="Select directory",
    directory=HOME_PATH,
    options=QFileDialog.Option.ShowDirsOnly,
)
```

`directory` and `options` do not work. 
Init path is wrong. 
Files get displayed, i can not select a directory.

[image: Directory only fail]

Comment: PyQt6 has introduced a [change in Enum usage](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/pyqt5_differences.html), which now all require the full namespace. Change to `QFileDialog.Option.ShowDirsOnly`.

Comment: @musicamante thanks! This resolves the error. ShowDirsOnly still does not work tho, same as the directory path... meaning i do not start at the path i specified and viewing dirs only fails, meaning i end up selecting a file...

Comment: We don't know what `HOME_PATH` is, so we cannot know if that's a valid path or not. Also, `getExistingDirectory` already shows directories only, try removing that option, as it's not necessary. Finally, specify what Qt version (`QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR`) and OS you're using.

Comment: @musicamante i updated the description. "getExistingDirectory already shows directories only" is not the case for me.

Comment: That seems a bug related to the native Gnome file dialog (as reported in [QTBUG-88709](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88709); I can't see further comments for newer Ubuntu/Gnome versions, which *might* mean that it was solved by recent version of those environments. As a workaround, use the Qt dialog with the `QFileDialog.Option.DontUseNativeDialog` option.

Comment: @musicamante Perfect! Thanks for the quick and accurate answer explaining the problem and providing the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question was mainly related to the new way PyQt6 uses Enums, which now always require the full namespace: until PyQt5, the syntax `Class.FlagName` was sufficient, but PyQt6 now requires `Class.EnumName.FlagName`.

The other issue is probably related to [QTBUG-88709](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88709) and is part of a long series of issues that deal with native dialogs provided by the OS, which always depend on the system.

There is no direct solution for this, and the only safe way is to enforce the [`DontUseNativeDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) flag whenever in doubt:

```py
dir_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
    parent=self,
    caption="Select directory",
    directory=HOME_PATH,
    options=QFileDialog.Option.DontUseNativeDialog,
)
```

Note that:

1. the `ShowDirsOnly` is useless as it's always set whenever the file dialog is in `Directory` mode (which is automatically done for the `getExistingDirectory()` static function);
2. using the non-native dialog will obviously be inconsistent with the normal dialog shown by the OS;
3. it is unclear if the bug was automatically resolved in Ubuntu/Gnome versions following the environment normally used in Ubuntu 20.04;
4. there is no direct way to enforce the workaround only when required: either you find out the *specific* cause of the issue, or you just assume it doesn't work and always use the non-native dialog;